# What is the right type of equation to fit the following data

Tags: regression

I want to estimate the amount of unique social media users $N$, in a list of the $K$ most recent social media posts (i.e. I extract the user that posted each post).
I've made a few graphs based on the 1000 most recent instagram posts with #dog, as expected it looks like the more posts I have, the more likely it will be that a post was made by a previously discovered user, but the problem is that I have no idea what the theoretical model would be behind the scenes here, and so don't know what kind of equation to fit.

On the 2nd graph I've tried to fit exponential/ logarithmic and linear curves, and got $0.9<R^2<0.92$ for all of them (when making sure the curve passes through the point (1,100))

The third graph seems to be linear ($R^2~0.9997$) but that doesn't seem to capture much about the actual process. Though maybe I'm just overcomplicating things and that is just fine? At the end of the day, I need to be able to predict how many posts I'll need to gather in order to get a set amount of users, for any previously unknown hashtag, by first getting a small sample.

EDIT: I tried using partial data (first 100, first 500) to recreate the third graph, and got the same confidence, for different equations. This seems to mean that there is a slow but significant change in slope that ends up making all earlier data irrelevant. Since I want to use a few hundred data points to predict what would happen with tens of thousands of data points, this is not good enough.

In order of what seems the most informative to me to the least, here are some graphs.

1. The distance between two occurrences of duplicate users (the x axis is essentially meaningless, it just counts the total occurrences):

[image: The distance between two occurrences of duplicate users (the x axis is essentially meaningless, it just counts the total occurrences)]

2. The percentage of posts that yielded new users up to each post / the number of posts

[image: The percentage of posts that yielded new users up to each post / the number of posts]

3. The number of unique users / the number of posts

[image: The number of unique users / the number of posts]